# dequeue not work

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-enqueue-script

i use a [plugin](http://www.broobe.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-jquery-timelinr/) that containing this code and i want to change js location to be located in my template directory instead of plugin without editing the plugin files

```
class jqueryTimelinrLoad  {

  public function registerScripts()

    {

        if (!wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'registered' )) wp_register_script( 'jquery' );



        wp_deregister_script('jquery.timelinr');

        wp_register_script('jquery.timelinr', JQTL_BASE_URL . '/assets/js/jquery.timelinr-1.0.js', array( 'jquery' ));

    }
     public function loadScripts() {

            if (!is_admin()) {

                if (!wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'queue' )) wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );



                wp_enqueue_script('jquery.timelinr', JQTL_BASE_URL . '/assets/js/jquery.timelinr-1.0.js', array( 'jquery' ));

            }

        }
}
```

i try this and it add the new link but old link also still

```
function drw_timeline_js () {

        $result = $GLOBALS["jqueryTimelinrLoad"]->loadScripts();


        wp_dequeue_script('jquery.timelinr');
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery.timelinr');


        wp_enqueue_script('jquery.timelinr2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.timelinr-1.0.js', array( 'jquery' ));

        return $result;
    }
add_action('init', 'drw_timeline_js', 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scripts should be enqueued on `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook, which runs after `init` action. So dequeuing on `init` won't work because sripts are not enqueued yet. Before enqueued scripts are printed, `wp_print_scripts` action is triggered so you can dequeue or unregister scripts safely at this moment:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'drw_timelinr_dequeue' );
function drw_timelinr_dequeue () {

     wp_dequeue_script('jquery.timelinr');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'drw_timeline_js');
function drw_timeline_js () {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.timelinr2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.timelinr-1.0.js', array( 'jquery' ));


}
```

Comment: the same problem it add the new link but not remove the old one

Comment: it works ,, thx alot

Comment: Yeah!!! If the answer fix your problem, please consider to mark the answer as accepted (left upper corner, bellow voting buttons there is a check mark).

Answer (score 1):

If `loadScripts()` is registered/enqueued correctly (the code posted doesn't show the hook used) then is it enqueued on [`wp_enqueue_scripts` which runs well after `init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) so what you are doing is trying to remove something that hasn't been added yet, and will be added later. Assuming that:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'drw_timeline_js', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

[`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) will ensure that your code runs last on that hook.

I also don't see the reason,or the need for, the `$result = $GLOBALS["jqueryTimelinrLoad"]->loadScripts();` line or for the `return` line in your function.

Comment: sorry i add the rest of the code

Comment: This should be the right answer then. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes,but no change